# Improper token has been passed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm a pretty new python coder and I'm getting this same error over and over when trying to run  a discord bot. The code literally only logs into it and for some reason this error keeps popping up. I have attached the code below (I am aware of the unused imports, I need them for later, but this issue needs to be fixed first).

```
import requests
import time
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

token = 'my token'

intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

bot.run(token)
```

I was expecting this code to simply log into the bot and make it go online. I have tried everything I can think of. I've pasted the raw token into the bot.run(), I've regenerated it, I've stored it in a variable, I've tried with no intents, I've tried with all intents, I've tried using discord.Client() instead of commands.Bot(), I cannot think of anything else to do at this point.

Comment: What does your token look like? I of course don't mean you to post it, it needs to be a secret, but make sure it is the right format. It should look like `(24 characters).(6 characters).(38 characters)`, 70 characters in total including the dots (Old tokens were 59 characters long, those still work too). And make sure to pass it as a string.

Comment: MTAzNzA5MjcxNDIwMzg0ODc5NQ.G2XlCm.lXPeCA-CGg7a4PczWPYuFfcZ6O3LElX6n66hrs
(I regenerated it after this)

Comment: Has regenerating fixed it?

Comment: When I run your code snippet and paste in my discord token instead of `'my token'`, the bot logs in just fine. There has to be an issue with the actual token. Sorry I cannot help you further.

Comment: so then the issue is something to do with my visual studio or my discord.py?

Comment: No, your discord bot token is somehow wrong.

Comment: it seems the problem was actually that my discord.py was very outdated, thanks for the help anyways

Comment: Hmm interesting. As i wrote earlier the token length changed some time ago, the old version was probably only checking for the old token syntax. Glad you got it working